# How can I authenticate/authorize an Azure functions app with an app service?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure *app service* as well as a *functions app* (I am currently learning Azure and if there is another way to achieve what I want I am open to suggestions). The app service contains an easy table I'd like to sync with an app (which is already working) and I'd like to implement a function with a blob storage input binding or timer trigger that fills the easy table.

Since there does not seem to be an output binding for easy tables I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403522/2249175) and implemented the access with a `MobileServiceClient`.

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://my-app.azurewebsites.net");
var table = client.GetTable<MyTableClass>();
await table.InsertAsync(myObject);
```

This works as long as the table is publicly writeable, but of course it does not work when it is readable anonynomously, but writeable only for authenticated users. To authenticate my function I've created an Azure Active Directory and created an API key for the app within that AD, then I tried to authenticate the `MobileServiceClient` via

```
await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, 
                        new JObject {{"access_token", "<my API key>"}});
```

but this did not work out. I am always getting an error

> The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized).

Obviously this does not work out (using the API key that way was really just a shot in the dark), but I am not sure how to accomplish authentication from my function app. I know that when I'm using the `MobileServiceClient` from within an app, I can redirect the user to login, but this (obviously) does not work with a function.

**How can I authenticate my function** with an existing app service in order to write to a table that is not writeable anonymously?

Answer (score 0):

Simple access via API key is not possible with *app service*, but a full authentication via Active Directory is necessary to access the app service. To achieve this, the *ADAL* ([Active Directory Access Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)) can be used.

#### The `AuthenticationContext`

The ADAL defines `AuthenticationContext` class which is a helper to authenticate with an Active Directory. First create a new `AuthenticationContext`

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Directory ID>");
```

You can find the `Directory ID` by visiting *Azure Active Directory* in the Azure portal and then open *Properties* from *Azure Active Directory Menu*. In the *Properties* menu there is a text box containing the `Directory ID`.

#### Authenticate with Azure Active Directory

You can now authenticate with

```
var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
      "https://batch.core.windows.net/", 
      new ClientCredential("<app ID>", "<app secret>"));
```

I'm assuming that there already *is* an registered app. To **obtain the app ID** visit *Azure Active Directory* → *App registrations* → *<Your app>*, there you can find the *Application ID* (also under *Properties*).

Next you'll have to **create the secret key** for the app. Therefor visit *Azure Active Directory* → *App registrations* → *<Your app>* → *Keys*. There you can create a key, just enter a key name and an expiry and click save. The key will be shown after saving. (*Watch out:* The Key can't be restored afterwards. Save it somewhere.)

#### The `MobileServiceClient`

The last step is to create the `MobileServiceClient`. Since the UI login is not available we'll have to create the logged in user manually (see [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_the_auth_token_in_the_Mobile_Services_client_and_caching_the_user_rsquo_s_identity_Day_10_.aspx)).

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://my-app.azurewebsites.net");
client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser("Foo:123456789");
client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

Now the `MobileServiceClient` is authenticated and ready to be used.

#### Further reading

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth

Answer (score 0):

You an use managed service identity to authenticate your function to the app service.

> Your application can communicate with other Azure services as itself
>   using a managed Azure Active Directory identity.

You can see how to enable and work with managed identity here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not been able to try it out, but from what I've read it seems to me as if I'd still have to request the authentication token (not with ADAL but with `AzureServiceTokenProvider `), hence I don't really see how this makes things much simpler (besides not having to find out the tenant ID and the app secret myself).

Comment: This solution is the official supported way to execute requests "as a service" across multiple azure services. You marked your own answer but didn't even try to implement the proper way... seems fishy to me and will direct people to the wrong solution.

Comment: This is **not** the supported way, but a **preview** - so is the respective library. Anyway, I kept my solution unmarked, since I see that pointing to the future supported way has its right to exist and to be aknowledged, too.